# QMediaPlayer, как изменять громкость звука?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qmediaplayer

Пытаюсь управлять системной громкостью звука. 
Ничего дельного для такой задачи не нашел, кроме модуля `sound`. Импортировал его командой pip install.

А после этого появился интересный момент:

- если прописать в программе `import sound`, то все будет в порядке,
- но при написании `from sound import Sound` выдает ошибку
  `ImportError: cannot import name 'Sound' from 'sound' <путь>`.

Как мне исправить ошибку, ведь я не смог найти других модулей, способных изменять громкость звука?

Comment: Если [это](https://pypi.org/project/sound/) имеется ввиду, то я не вижу в нём никакого `Sound`. Вижу `Snd`.

Comment: Snd тоже не видит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `QMediaPlayer` позволяет воспроизводить медиаисточник.

> `volume` : int
>
> Это свойство содержит текущую громкость воспроизведения.
>
> Громкость воспроизведения линейно масштабируется в диапазоне от 0 (тишина) до 100 (полная громкость). Значения вне этого диапазона будут ограничены.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSlider, QPushButton, QGridLayout


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        
        self.volumeslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeslider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.volumeslider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.change_volume)
        self.volumeslider.setValue(100)
        self.volume = self.volumeslider.value()

        play_btn  = QPushButton('Play')   
        play_btn.clicked.connect(self.playMedia)
        pause_btn = QPushButton('Pause')  
        pause_btn.clicked.connect(self.pauseMedia)
        stop_btn  = QPushButton('Stop')   
        stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stopMedia)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(play_btn, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(pause_btn, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(stop_btn, 0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.volumeslider, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(
            'http://europaplus.hostingradio.ru:8014/ep-top256.mp3'
        )))        
        
        self.player.setVolume(self.volume) 
        self.player.play()        
        
    def change_volume(self, value):
        self.player.setVolume(value)
        
    def playMedia(self):
        self.player.play()  

    def pauseMedia(self):
        self.player.pause()        
        
    def stopMedia(self):
        self.player.stop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]